# Group of positive rationals under multiplication not isomorphic to group of rationals

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

A question that may sound very trivial, apologies beforehand. I am wondering why $( \mathbb{Q}_{>0} , \times )$ is not isomorphic to $( \mathbb{Q} , + )$. I can see for the case when $( \mathbb{Q} , \times )$, not required to be positive, one can argue the group contains elements with order 2 (namely all negatives). In the case of the requirement for all rationals to be positive this argument does not fly. What trivial fact am I missing here?

Comment: This is Exercise II.4.6 in Aluffi Chapter 0. I was also struggling with it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The isomorphism would have to map some element of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ to $2$. There is no element of $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0},\times)$ whose square is $2$, but whatever number is mapped to $2$ has a half in $(\mathbb{Q},+)$. More generally speaking, you can divide by any natural number $n$ in $(\mathbb{Q},+)$, but you can't generally draw $n$-th roots in $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0},\times)$. More abstractly speaking, you can introduce an invertible multiplication operation on $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ to turn it into a field (in fact that in a sense is the point of the construction of $\mathbb{Q}$) but you can't define a corresponding exponentiation operation within $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0},\times)$.

The isomorphism that you expected to exist exists not between $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0},\times)$ but between $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and $(b^\mathbb{Q},\times)$ for any $b\in\mathbb{R}_{>0} \setminus\{1\}$. Since $b^\mathbb{Q}$ always contains irrational elements, this is never a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0},\times)$.

Comment: More-or-less, joriki's answer can be rephrased like this. If we find a property, which is preserved by isomorphisms and which is fulfilled only for one of the groups, then the groups are not isomorphic. In this case, the property of the group $(G,\circ)$ is $(\forall x\in G)(\exists y\in G) y\circ y=x$.

Comment: Martin's comment referred to an earlier version of the answer that only had the first couple of sentences.

Comment: It might be added that the property mentioned here (being avle to divide by any natural number n, which would then correspond to being able to take n'th roots in the multiplicative case) is called being divisible.

Comment: To clarify that slightly (since "being able to divide" is a property of humans and computers, not of groups :-): A group is called divisible if for each element $x$ and each natural number $n$ there is an element $y$ such that $ny$, defined as the $n$-fold sum of $y$, is $x$. Then $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is divisible and $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0},\times)$ isn't.

Comment: The generalization of the result mentioned by Martin Sleziak can be found in Kuratowski's and Mostowski's "Set theory" (p.85 of the 2-nd edition). Given an isomorphism *f* between two algebraic systems (not necessarily groups), the result allows to "build" the whole spectrum of formulas preserved by *f*.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental theorem of arithmetic exactly says that $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}, \times)$ is an abelian free group with the set of primes as a basis. Therefore, if $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}, \times)$ and $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ were isomorphic, $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ would be an abelian free group.

Suppose by contradiction that $X$ is a free basis of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and let $x \in X$. Then there exist $x_1,\dots,x_m \in X$ and $a_1, \dots,a_m \in \mathbb{Z}$ (uniquely determined) so that $$ \frac{x}{n} = a_1x_1+ \dots + a_mx_m,$$ hence $$x= na_1x_1+ \dots+ na_mx_m.$$ Consequently, there exists $1 \leq i \leq m$ such that $x=na_ix_i=na_ix$ ie. $na_i=1$; a contradiction with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ when $n>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, to the contrary, that there is an isomorphism $\phi:(\mathbb Q,+)\to(\mathbb Q_{>0},\times)$. Then, there must be an $a\in\mathbb Q$ such that $\phi(a)=2$. Thus,
$$\phi(a)=\phi(a/2+a/2)=\phi(a/2)\times \phi(a/2)=2 \, ,$$
which is absurd, since $2$ does not have a square root in $(\mathbb Q_{>0},\times)$.

More conceptually, $(\mathbb Q,+)$ is a divisible group, whereas $(\mathbb Q_{>0},\times)$ is not. A *divisible group* is a group (usually assumed to be commutative) where for every positive integer $n$ and $g\in G$, there is a $h\in G$ such that $h^n=g$. In additive notation, this condition would be written $nh=g$. The above proof exploits the fact that $(\mathbb Q_{>0},\times)$ is not divisible; specificially, if $n=2$ and $g=2$, then there is no $h\in\mathbb Q_{>0}$ such that $h^n=g$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi_p$ be the projection onto prime $p$, i.e. if $r=\prod_{q~\mathrm{prime}} q^{\alpha_q}\in\mathbb Q$, then $\pi_p(r)=p^{\alpha_p}$. It is easily seen to be a endomorphism of $(\mathbb Q_{>0},\times)$. For distinct primes $p\ne p'$, $\pi_p\circ\pi_{p'}$ is trivial, which means the endomorhpism ring of $(\mathbb Q_{>0},\times)$ has zero divisors. However, $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{Q})\cong \mathbb{Q}$ is a field, which does not have one.