# Isomorphism between $\mathbb Q$ under addition and $\mathbb Q^+$ under multiplication?

Tags: group-theory

An exercise asks me to show that $\mathbb Q \times C_2$ (under addition of the rationals) is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q-\{0\}$ under multiplication. Quotienting $\mathbb Q \times C_2$ by $C_2$ gives $\mathbb Q$ under addition. The only element of order 2 in $\mathbb Q-\{0\}$ is -1, so quotienting out by $<-1>$ gives $\mathbb Q^+$ under multiplication. But I don't think $\mathbb Q$ under addition and $\mathbb Q^+$ under multiplication can be isomorphic. If $f$ were such an isomorphism from the additive group to the multiplicative group, then $f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ would have to be $f(1)^\frac{a}{b}$. But no matter which positive rational $r$ I pick to be $f(1)$ there will be a rational $q$ such that $r^q$ is irrational, unless I let $r=1$ in which case $f$ would not be injective.

Where did I mess up? Am I not allowed to say that the quotients of both groups by $C_2$ are isomorphic?

Comment: what's $C_2$  ? (obligatory extra characters)

Comment: The cyclic group of order $2$, I assume.

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/group-of-positive-rationals-under-multiplication-not-isomorphic-to-group-of-rati?rq=1

Comment: Yes, it's the cyclic group of order 2.
So did the exercise ask me to prove a false statement?

Comment: @Nishant Yes, the exercise is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Your isomorphism works with $\Bbb R$ instead of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^{\ast}$ should be isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, not $ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q}$.  The isomorphism is given by

$$(-1)^{\epsilon} \prod\limits_p p^{a_p} \mapsto ((\epsilon + 2 \mathbb{Z}), (a_p)_p)$$

where $p$ runs through the prime numbers.  This follows from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.