# Are the additive group of rationals and the multiplicative group of positive rationals isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, logarithms, group-isomorphism

### This question is a little bit different from [Group of positive rationals under multiplication not isomorphic to group of rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/group-of-positive-rationals-under-multiplication-not-isomorphic-to-group-of-rati) since I was wondering if logarithmic function could solve this or not, thank you.

Consider two groups $(\mathbb Q^+,\cdot)$ and $(\mathbb Q,+)$, does an isomorphism exist between them?

My attempt: Let $\varphi:\mathbb Q^+\rightarrow\mathbb Q$ be the isomorphic function, then the below statement must hold true for all $a,b\in\mathbb Q^+$:
$$\varphi(a\cdot b)=\varphi(a)+\varphi(b)$$
So I guess maybe a logarithmic function would be fine here, since it's bijective, too.

But the problem is I can not show for a specific base like $10$ for example, $\log(\mathbb Q^+)=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Had the question been about $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\mathbb{R}$, the answer would have been different (and easier), because here $\log : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ is truly a bijection, and in fact a group isomorphism. However, when restricted to $\mathbb{Q}^+$, most values of $\log$ are still irrational (in fact, transcendental, this is a transcendental function), so it will not work here.

Comment: @Najib thank you, I explained how it has some difference in the top of the problem text. if it's still not acceptable, tell me to close my question.

Comment: Since the answers to the other question already prove the two groups are not isomorphic, there can be *no* isomorphism.

Comment: @egreg Yes sir, but at first I was not aware of that..

Comment: The answer that you accepted is the same (up to rewording) as the accepted answer of the duplicate thread. How are the two questions *not* duplicate?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

HINT: For each $q\in\Bbb Q$ the equation $x+x=q$ has a solution; is it true that $x\cdot x=q$ has a solution for each $q\in\Bbb Q^+$?

Comment: Thanks, got it! there is simply no isomorphism between them..

Comment: @Amir: That’s right. You’re welcome!

Comment: But generally, is it true that $\log_{10}(\mathbb Q^+)=\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @Amir: No, because $\log_{10}2$, for instance, is irrational.

Comment: Oh yes, and if it was, then also the above problem had an answer :]..

Comment: I am so, so tired of people giving one-line "hint" answers to questions that have already been asked dozens of times and already have long, elaborate answers (in this case the duplicate was even the first question in the "Related" section of the sidebar).

Comment: @Najib Alright, chill-out we are just learning from each other. I usually search my question to not to be repetitive, maybe I missed it this time. not a big deal. 
If others see this as a duplicate one, with a few more votes it would be closed.

Comment: @Najib: The allegedly related links are useless often enough that I don’t automatically look at them, especially when (as in this case) I don’t immediately recognize it as a duplicate and can provide a good answer as soon as the question appears. And get rid of the scare quotes: it is a hint answer, not a ‘hint’ answer, it’s a good one, and in this case it proved to be an effective one as well. And I’ll choose effective teaching and getting questions answered usefully and promptly ahead of keeping the books straight any day; duplicates can be identified and cross-referenced at any time.

Answer (score 3):

So now you know they're not isomorphic, but you can go a bit further with what you already know. For example, $\mathbb{Q}^+$ has a subgroup whose elements are the powers $2^n$ of $2$, including $1$ and $1/2$, etc. Because the map $n \mapsto 2^n$ from $(\mathbb Z,+)$ is injective, this is a cyclic subgroup. You can do the same thing with the powers $3^n$ and see these two subgroups intersect only in $\{1\}$.

Now, you know every natural number has a unique factorization in terms of primes. Can you use that to say more about $(\mathbb Q^+,\cdot)$?

By comparison, you can check for any two elements $g$ and $h$ of $(\mathbb Q,+)$,there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $mg = nh$. This means that, in contrast to the case of $(\mathbb Q^+,\cdot)$, any two cyclic subgroups have a nontrivial intersection. One says that $(\mathbb Q^+,\cdot)$ has *[rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group)* equal to 1, meaning there's a $\mathbb Z$ subgroup, but only one independent such $\mathbb Z$ subgroup, in that all other isomorphic copies of $\mathbb Z$ meet it nontrivially.