# Prove groups $(\mathbb{R}_+,\times)$ and $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},\times)$ are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Prove that group of positive real numbers with multiplication is not isomorphic to group of real numbers without zero with multiplication

Comment: Similar question about rationals: [Group of positive rationals under multiplication not isomorphic to group of rationals](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/33607).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there existed an isomorphism $$\varphi : \mathbb{R}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$$
it would be in particular a bijection. However it should also satisfy that $\varphi (ab)=\varphi (a) \varphi(b)$. So let's examine $\varphi(-1)$.

$$\varphi (1)= \varphi((-1)(-1)) = (\varphi(-1))^2.$$
Now, since this is a homomorphism, it should be true that $$\varphi (1) = 1,$$
so $$(\varphi(-1))^2 = 1$$ since $\varphi(-1) \in \mathbb{R}_+$, $$\varphi(-1)=1,$$ so it would not be an injection, hence it would not be an isomorpshim.

Answer (score 0):

How many solutions are there to the equation $x^2=1$ in both groups?

Note that $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic, they have to have the same number of solutions to $x^2=1$. Let $\varphi: G \to G'$ be an isomorphism. Suppose that $a^2=1$ in $G$. Then $1=\varphi(1)=\varphi(a^2)=\varphi(a)^2$, so $\varphi(a)$ is a solution to $x^2=1$ in $G'$. Conversely, if $a^2=1$ in $G'$, consider the inverse isomorphism $\varphi^{-1}: G' \to G$. We have $1=\varphi^{-1}(1)=\varphi^{-1}(a^2)=\varphi^{-1}(a)^2$, so $\varphi^{-1}(a)$ is a solution to $x^2=1$ in $G$. So for every solution to $x^2=1$ in one of the groups, there is a (unique - because $\varphi, \varphi^{-1}$ are isomorphisms) corresponding solution to $x^2=1$ in the other group. Thus we obtain a 1-1 correspondence between solutions to $x^2=1$ in $G$ and solutions to $x^2=1$ in $G'$.

Comment: Don't get all the jargon after your spot on question "How many solutions are there to the equation $x^2=1$ in each of the two groups?" only one in $\mathbb R_+$, but two in $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$.  The number of solutions to $x^2 = 1$ is preserved by isomorphism... hence...

Comment: I have edited for clarity.

Comment: I think you just messed up:  $x^2 = 1$ has two solutions in $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}: \;\;x = 1, x= -1.$  However, in $ \mathbb R_+, $ the only solution to $x^2 = 1$ is $x=1$.

Comment: I began the second paragraph by saying "if they were isomorphic..." so everything that follows is based on that assumption. Since we know in fact there are different numbers of solutions to $x^2=1$ in the two groups, they cannot be isomorphic. I have edited again to clarify this.

Comment: kudos...(I guess I just worry that the part after "if they were isomorphic" may confuse and already confused OP.  But your answer is, indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

Any homomorphism $h:\mathbb{R}_+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ clearly satisfies $h(1)=1$. Moreover, we claim $h(b)>0$ for all $b\in \mathbb{R}_+$.

Indeed, for all $a\in \mathbb{R}_+$, $h(a^2)={h(a)}^2>0$. It suffice to note that every $b\in\mathbb{R}_+$ there is some $a\in\mathbb{R}_+$ with $a^2=b$.

It follows that $h$ can never be surjective, and hence cannot be an isomorphism.